# Redirection error on live server using php codeigniter and filezilla

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

We are working php codeigniter framework, when we run project on the Localhost it works without any issue, but when we live it on the server then some button are not working properly.
When the user press the signin button then the page redirect to the Home page instead of redirecting to the User Profile page.

```
/*Htaccess File*/
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^jp_sys.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^jp_app.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule> 
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Code in .htaccess works for me........

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```